# Using JQuery alongside an image sprite

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-sprites

I'm currently using CSS and an image sprite for my navigation (code below). 
This works just as intended, however I'd like to ease this transition with a fade.

I believe it is best to use JQuery for this, however I would like to leave the CSS in order to add support for those with Javascript disabled. Can anybody point me in the right direction of how to achieve this 'collaboration'?!

*HTML:*

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="home"><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

*CSS:*

```
nav
{
    margin-top: 17px;
    float: right;
}

nav #menu
{
    display: block;
    height: 22px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

nav #menu li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 28px;
}

nav #menu li a
{
    background: url(/Content/Images/navigation.png) no-repeat;
    height: 22px;
    display: block;
}

nav #menu #home 
{
    width: 53px;
}

nav #menu #home a:hover
{
    background-position: 0 -22px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do one of two things:

1) Experiment with the `animate` function in jQuery.
2) Create a wrapper in the `li`:

```
<ul>
    <li><span class="bg-image" /><a href="#"></li>
</ul>
```

Then use jQuery like so:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#menu li a").bind("mouseover", function () {
        $(this).siblings("span.bg-image").css("background", "url(URL TO IMAGE)").hide().fadeIn(100);
    })
});
```

Repeat and use the not hot image for mouseout. I am assuming you would use a transparent place holder type image for the not hot state, make sure the width/height is the same for the hot class.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to the *body* and remove it with javascript just after opening.

```
<body class="nojs">
<script>$("body").removeClass("nojs").addClass("js")</script>
```

Now in the css you can add any rules for everyone without javascript

```
.nojs #boton1:hover {background: url(navigation.png) no-repeat;}
```

And to create rules only for people with javascript activated

```
.js #boton1 {}
```